# Python-Bigquery Client Library. Persist client object to make more than one query

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-oauth

I am creating a BigQuery client object in python using BigQuery client library, by authenticating on Google consent screen. In order to avoid making user authorize himself twice, I want to re-utilize the client object for both queries. I have tried following:

1) Pickle client object using pickle library. :

```
Error
  'Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.',
_pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported.
Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.
```

2) Pickle client object using dill library.

```
Error
Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.',
_pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported.
Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.
```

3) Created a flask session and store client object as a session variable. In this case object is getting converted to dictionary with an error message

```
'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'query''
```

Comment: Please, give us more details about your use case. Where is the user getting access and why are you using oauth 2 and not the [Google Sign-In](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/authenticating-users)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to authorize user twice with oauth 2.0. Once token is created it can be reused and refreshed, more [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#credentials).

Additionally if you use flask, the [example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app#example) in the documentation shows how to store credentials in flask session and access them multiple times if necessary:

```
  # Store credentials in the session.
  # ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save these
  #              credentials in a persistent database instead.
  credentials = flow.credentials
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
```

and

```
  # Load credentials from the session.
  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
      **flask.session['credentials'])
```